# Preload external page for display in Fancybox (lightbox) popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, preload

I have a page which uses [Fancybox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to display images and/or external pages depending on user actions. I've been loading the pages using an iframe as so:

```
$('#userbtnclick1').click(function() {
  $.fancybox({
    'height' : $(window).height()*0.75,
    'width' : $(window).width()*0.75,
    'href' : 'http://an.external.destination.com',
    'title' : 'fancybox caption',
    'type' : 'iframe'
  });
});
```

Though it's apparent some of the external pages take a while to load and in the meantime the screen is lightbox-blank. I see Fancybox has an AJAX method but that seems like it was designed for snippets of pages, not entire external sites.

Would it be possible to asynchronously preload an external site in my $(document).ready{}, store it perhaps as a hidden DIV, then call it when the user clicks the button? The idea being that it would have loaded by the time the user clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Remove 'type' and 'href', add 'content' and set its value to $('#div-where-your-preloaded-content-is').